# Using python to sum n terms of a sequence using only for and while loops

Tags: python

I am having to ask the user for an input for n amount of terms and also their chosen value for x for this sequence.

```
x^5/5 - x^7/7 + x^9/9 - x^11/11 + ...
```

I am having trouble accounting for the sign change every other term, and can't use any if statements.

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

My code so far:

```
print(" ")
print("Please enter the number of terms you would like to sum up.")
print("The sequence is x^5/5-x^7/7+x^9/9-...")
print(" ")
n=int(input('Number = '))
print(" ")
print("Please enter the number for x.")
print(" ")
x=int(input('x = '))
#
nsum=0
for i in range(5,n+6,2):
    coefficient=1/i
    for j in range(5,i+1,2):
        coefficient=-1*coefficient
    nsum=nsum+coefficient*x**i
#
print(nsum)
```

Comment: Is this python 2 or 3?

Comment: @LuminousNutria It's python 3.7

Comment: Tip: `(-1)**even == 1` and `(-1)**odd == -1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sequence shows the nth term is positive if n is odd, negative if it is even. So you can do this in your for loop. Also in your code the user input n does not equal to the number of terms:

```
nsum=0
for index in range(0, n):
    coefficient=(-1)**(index)
    i =  2*index + 5
    nsum=nsum+coefficient*x**i/i
```

Comment: this works for n=1 and x=1, but i tried n=2 and x=1 to calculate 1/5 - 1/7 but I got 0.4857...etc when it should be 0.0571...etc.

Comment: I thought you only had problems with the sign so didn't check the logic. I've fixed the for loop now.

Comment: This again works for n=1 and x=1 but not for when n=2. I thought of a solution like that after posting my problem, sorry to be a pain! It calculates 1/5 + 1/7 instead of 1/5 - 1/7, as the coefficients for both when i=5 and 7 are (-1)**6 and (-1)**8, both equalling 1.

Comment: I see the mistake now. Sorry about that. I think the easiest might be to use enumerate and get access to index directly.

Comment: Unfortunately I am restricted to only for and while loops for this question, otherwise I would!

Comment: Your prompt asks user to enter number of terms (n). But in your code that is not really the case (n = 3 does not give you 3 terms). I've fixed it so n gives you the number of terms, and you calculate the sign and i based on n.